# Property of big O notation multiplication

Tags: limits, asymptotics

In this document here: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/595ama/ama-ch2.pdf on page 15, there is a property about pulling out factors for big O notation. Specifically, if $f(x) = O(g(x)h(x))$ then $f(x) = g(x)O(h(x))$. Is the converse true as well? That is if $f(x) = g(x)O(h(x))$ then $f(x) = O(g(x)h(x))$?

Comment: Always use the definitions. As in the A by StuartMN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(H(x)) = any function G(x) with |$\frac{G(x)}{H(x)}$| $\leqslant$ M (that is ,bounded by a real number M over some range of the variable "x") . So yes ,Your 
two equality's are equivalent  since dividing f by gh is the same as dividing f over g by h.